# Scatterplot "Error in if (counts[i] == 0) next : argument is of length zero"

Tags: r, error-handling, scatter-plot

I hope anybody can help me.

I have run a scatterplot using quantile regression, the code I used is

```
library(carData)
scatterplotMatrix(~ mpg + wt| cyl, data=mtcars, main="Scatterplot Matrix via 
car package", col=c(1,2,3))
```

This runs perfectly perfect but,
Now I just want to plot the top right frame of the scatterplot using the next code

```
scatterplot(mpg ~ wt | cyl, data = mtcars, lwd=2, col=c(1,2,3))
```

but the system send me the next warning

> "Error in if (counts[i] == 0) next : argument is of length zero"

and it seems that the scatteplot was interrupted or sth, because the plote generated shows a part of the scatterplot but not entirely.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: When I run `scatterplot(mpg ~ wt | cyl, data = mtcars, lwd=2, col=c(1,2,3))` the plot renders correctly without error.  (To be explicit, using `car::scatterplot()`.)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to make the cyl grouping a factor

```
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
scatterplot(mpg ~ wt | cyl, data = mtcars, lwd=2, col=c(1,2,3))
```

[image]